# How to install Q properly?

Tags: kdb

I have a job interview and one of the stages is an assessment to see how, as a beginner, I would tackle a series of problems using Q. The company have provided a link on how to install Q and I have installed it up until it mentions defining q as a command. I have repeated this process numerous times and nothing seems to change. Am I supposed to create a QHOME folder?

Here is a link to the installation guide: https://code.kx.com/q/learn/install/windows/

Comment: Its not so important to define the command, but first you should ensure you are able to run the executable.  Were you able to successfully run ```C:\q\w64\q``` or ```C:\q\w32\q``` and achieve a ```q)``` prompt?

Comment: Yes i can run and achieve a q) prompt

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a QHOME environment variable, or add C:\q\w32 to your "path" environment variable. I use the latter

Try this on windows: Start -> Right click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> Path -> Edit -> add `;C:\q\w32` to the end of your path and save.

Then when you open a new command prompt you should just be able to type `q` and it will start q/kdb (assuming you've installed 32bit version to C:\q as per the instructions)

Comment: what should my path look like?

Comment: There will likely be a collection of semi-colon separated values ```"C:\Program Files\x\;C:Program Files\y\"```, it depends what you have previously installed.  You can just edit this and append the string in the answer.